# Can I buy two tickets for different passports, register for them, go to the transit zone, cancel one and fly to the other

Tags: passports, tickets, borders

Can I theoretically buy two tickets while abroad, register for both of these flights at the airport.  Then go to the transit zone with one passport and ticket (the passport with which I entered the country), and fly away with another ticket.  Additional conditions: Surnames in these passports and tickets are different.

@jcaron ask me for the whole story and problem I am trying to solve.

So, this is my story.

My girlfriend and I are Ukrainians who lived in the occupied Crimea. We both took Russian passports in 2014 because we had to take them if we wanted to take care of our old parents and live in peace in this territory. But we have kept our Ukrainian ID because we hoped that someday we will be able to move to Ukraine or Ukraine will be able to take Crimea back under its control.

In 2019, my girlfriend and I got married (BUT ONLY IN RUSSIA NOT IN UKRAINE) and she took my last name. In the Ukrainian identity card, her maiden name left

When the war started in Ukraine, my wife and I realized that we had to leave Russia if we didn't want to suffer from the war. So, we have issued Russian international passports. Obviously my wife's Russian passport was with her new surname.

In March 2022, the Government of Canada provides a special program for citizens of Ukraine. This is the CUAET program. We took part in it. Since we do not have Ukrainian international passports, in September 2022 we reached travel documents for one trip (SGTM) from the Canadian IRCC service.

But the problem is that my wife's last name on her Ukrainian ID and SGTM is her Ukrainian maiden name. We can't tell IRCC about our Russian IDs and our marriage because all the documents issued by Russia in Crimea are not valid almost all over the world (in Canada too). So for Canada we are not married and my wife is still with her maiden name.

At the end of October we are going to move to Canada. Our flight will be from St. Petersburg with a transfer at Istanbul Airport. For the first part of the flight, my wife will be checking in with her Russian passport, because the Russian border guard checks whether your boarding pass matches your passport or not. And if they see her maiden name, they will ask what its going on, and then if she gives a Ukrainian identity card, it will be a problem, and even my wife may not be allowed to cross the border due her ukrainian citizenship. Yes border officer break the law, but thats reality in Russia, so deal wit it.

Then, when we arrive in Istanbul, we will pass the Turkish border on Russian passports, collect our luggage and check in for another flight (a flight to Canada) on our single trip travel documents. Then we are going to cross the border again to get to the transit zone.

And at this point, we potentially have a problem. We have to leave Turkey on the passport that we are arriving in Turkey. And this is russian internatioanl passports. But the boarding pass for the flight from Turkey will have a surname that does not match the Russian passport. And if we check in for a flight on a Russian passport, then Canadians border officers will ask us uncomfortable questions about our passport situation, because we didnt tell Canada about our russian passports and citizensip, so and we want to avoid this.

I thought for a long time how to avoid this problem. And I didn’t come up with anything better than a two-ticket scheme. If it helps, we are will fly with the same company all the time. It will be Turkish Airlines.

Tip for the future: NEVER LIVE IN OCCUPIED TERRITORY OR SOMETHIG LIKE GREY-LAW TERRITORY. YOU WILL SUFFER ALL THE TIME WHEN YOU GOING TO INTERACT THE REST OF THE WORLD.

Comment: I suspect that at some airports this might be relatively easy while at others security procedures will make this difficult if not impossible.

Comment: Ok, I would like to know this regarding Istanbul Airport (IST)

Comment: Why buy two tickets? You can pass exit control on one and check in with the other passport in most countries. And if you try to avoid legal problems or military service you may still be found on the list of departing passengers and taken out of the plane or at boarding.

Comment: @Willeke.
I'm not military.
This concerns the war in Ukraine, life in the occupied territories and the chaos in the documents that follows.
That's right, I can go through border control with one passport and buy a ticket for another. But don't you need to show your boarding pass when you go through border control, where your name and surname are written? If I buy a ticket for one passport (FirstName1Surname1), get a boarding pass with these data, and then go through border control with a passport (FirstName1Surname2), then there will be problems. And to avoid this, I want to apply my idea.

Comment: Passport inspectors at some airports do check boarding passes; at others they don't.  I don't remember how it is in Istanbul.

Comment: It’s probably easier if you tell us the problem you are actually trying to solve. But the answer probably depends a lot not only on the origin airport but also the destination (if they require API/APIS and/or ETA/ESTA or other prior notification this may complicate things), whether you have checked bags or not, whether you expect to get a refund for unused ticket… Also if you get to a check-in desk and it’s not very busy and an agent notices you checking in twice with two different names that is probably going to draw quite a bit of attention. Expect a long chat with the police.

Comment: Depending on the actual reason for wanting to juggle with two passports, this answer may be useful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/52101/30703

Comment: It is Canada's problem on whether to recognize Russian documents in the illegally annexed parts in Ukraine; it is your responsibility to provide all pertinent, truthful information. But two tickets should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I made a mistake when I didn’t say in the application that we have Russian documents from the occupied territory. When we arrive to Canada I'm going to tell whole truth to imigratioal officer if he were ready to listen me.
Anyway we are going to not hide any part of our story. We didn't say about our russian documents only because we thought that documents was not valid  in Canada. This is a mistake made out of stupidity, not malicious intent.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I theoretically buy two tickets while abroad, register for both of these flights at the airport.

Yes, provided that by "registering" you mean "check in and get a boarding pass" AND that each passport allows entry at the destination of it's respective ticket.

> Then go to the transit zone with one passport and ticket (the passport with which I entered the country),

Yes, but you do NOT need a ticket do do that. In almost all cases you can just present one passport/boarding pass at the security ID check and the other passport at immigration.

> and fly away with another ticket. Additional conditions: Surnames in these passports and tickets are different.

No one is going to prevent you from flying but there may be other consequences depending on how the airlines manage the passenger manifest and the specific destinations.

This whole plot seems needlessly complicated and entirely unnecessary. The passport you use at check-in is ONLY used to verify your ability to enter the destination country. It's perfectly legal and fairly common to use a different passport at the exit control at the airport. There you should use the same passport you have used to enter the country, regardless of what passport you are using for flying. I have done so many times.

Example: when I fly from Germany to the US, I use my US passport to check-in and get the boarding pass. I use my German passport at the exit immigration control.

The only potential problem I can see in your case that you have different names on each passport. The only time that may be an issue is if the exit immigration officer wants to see your boarding pass (which IMO is rare these days). In this case, you can just show them your second passport (unless that's somehow illegal in your departing country).

Comment: (+1) Would it make any difference if the two flights were with the *same* airline? Are systems capable of picking up duplicate check-in?

Comment: Some are, some aren't. Most are protected against duplicate bookings on the same flight but not necessarily at the same time on different flights.

Comment: @Traveller given the fact that OP would have two different passports with two different names, it would be quite difficult to match the two flights. Even with the same name, there are too many people sharing the same name for them to reject such duplicates. The date of birth info which could help is (at least in theory) usually only for purposes of API/APIS, and I’m pretty sure that there are still many people with the same name and date of birth (especially in China). Finally, why would airlines care? As long as you pay for both tickets…